# bsddb3-6.0.1 Windows7 bulid error: _bsddb.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol db_create referenced in function newDBObject

Tags: python, windows, berkeley-db, bsddb

building bsddb3-6.0.1, Python 3.3.2, BerkeleyDB 5.3, Windows7. 
First linker asked for libdb53s.lib, but there's no such file, so I deleted 's' symbol (in setup3.py) and now linker can find libdb53.lib, but...

_bsddb.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol db_create referenced in f
unction newDBObject
_bsddb.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol db_strerror referenced in
 function makeDBError
_bsddb.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol db_env_create referenced
in function newDBEnvObject
_bsddb.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol db_version referenced in
function _promote_transaction_dbs_and_sequences
_bsddb.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol db_full_version reference
d in function _promote_transaction_dbs_and_sequences
_bsddb.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol db_sequence_create refere
nced in function newDBSequenceObject
build\lib.win-amd64-3.3\bsddb3_pybsddb.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved
externals
error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\amd6
4\link.exe"' failed with exit status 1120

Copied BDB folders to bsddb3-6.0.1\db 
bsddb3-6.0.1\db\lib contains libdb53.lib 
bsddb3-6.0.1\db\bin contains libdb53.dll 
Are there any ready to use bsddb3 binaries for Python3.3.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the 's' symbol isn't appropriate - the s designates the static libdb53 library.  Assuming you are building libdb53 from source as well, in the build_windows directory there is a Berkeley_DB.sln that includes Static_Debug and Static_Release configurations that will build these.

However, your troubles may not end there.  I'm using the static libraries and still getting similar unresolved external errors.